# Timely commit to DB using Golang

Tags: database, go

I successfully "batched" many statements in lots of 500-1000 rows to be Inserted at once. However this was using simple `for` loop and manually setting it to 500-1000 loops. Something like:

```
for i:=0;i<500;i++ {
   // Create a string of 500 values to be inserted at once
}
// Insert the 500 values
```

Is there a way I could timely `commit()` like: "commit each seconds" ?

Conceptually, I'd like to have something like;

```
// Create connection to DB
// Begin a transaction
// Prepare a statement

go timelyCommits(tx)  // spawn a commit ticker
for {
   // Constantly create string of values to be inserted like:
   // Values (1, "one"),(2,"two"),(3,"three")...(1000,"thousand")...
   // Insert without commit
}

func timelyCommits(tx){
   for {
      time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
      tx.Commit()
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't commit the same transaction multiple times. You need to start new transaction, then commit/rollback. What is your intention of doing *timely commit*?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah that is what I saw. I would like to optimize http post requests as much as possible. In fact, manually grouping inserts by batches of 500 lead me to 200.000 inserts/seconds, while sequential  one-by-one inserts only reached 25.000 inserts/seconds... It's day Vs night. So I'd like to have this grouping mechanism but I can't wait for 500 transactions to happen before commit, I need a timely mechanism like commiting every 10ms or so. Do you see another way around this ?

Comment: I summarized the idea in an additional answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimization is not a trivial task and may also involving database tuning, etc. Without detail knowledge about the system that you're trying to implement, it is difficult to give a proper advice. In addition to what already suggested in the answer, you may need to implement a kind of *buffering*, e.g. with channel which has fixed capacity. Then when *buffer* is `FULL` or timer `EXPIRED`, build the query then perform BULK INSERT in transaction. Try it at [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PrctKDXjM0-).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type DataBuffer struct {
    capacity int
    duration time.Duration

    incomingData chan interface{}
    full chan bool
    mustExit chan bool
    done chan bool

    query string
    args []interface{}
}

func NewDataBuffer(capacity int, dur time.Duration) *DataBuffer {
    buf := &DataBuffer {
        incomingData: make(chan interface{}, capacity),
        full: make(chan bool),
        args: make([]interface{}, capacity),
        duration: dur,
        mustExit: make(chan bool, 1),
        done: make(chan bool, 1),
    }
    return buf
}

func (b *DataBuffer) Append(d interface{}) {
    if !b.put(d) {
        //Notify that buffer is full
        //<- will wait until space available
        b.full <- true
        b.incomingData <- d
    }
}

func (b *DataBuffer) put(d interface{}) bool {
    //Try to append the data
    //If channel is full, do nothing, then return false
    select {
    case b.incomingData <- d:
        return true
    default:
        //channel is full
        return false
    }
}

func (b *DataBuffer) execTransaction() error {
    /*
        Begin transaction
        Insert Data Group 
        Commit/rollback
    */

    fmt.Print(time.Now())
    fmt.Println(b.query)
    fmt.Println(b.args)

    return nil
}

func (b *DataBuffer) clear() {
    //clear args
    nOldArg := len(b.args)
    for k := 0; k < nOldArg; k++ {
        b.args[k] = nil
    }
    b.args = b.args[:0]
    b.query = ""
}

func (b *DataBuffer) buildQuery() bool {
    ndata := len(b.incomingData)
    if ndata == 0 {
        return false
    }

    k := 0
    b.clear()

    //Build the query, adjust as needed
    b.query = "QUERY:"
    for data := range b.incomingData {
        b.query += fmt.Sprintf(" q%d", k) //build the query
        b.args = append(b.args, data)

        k++
        if k >= ndata {
            break
        }

    }
    return true
}

func (b *DataBuffer) doInsert() {
    if b.buildQuery() {
        b.execTransaction()
    }
}

func (b *DataBuffer) runAsync() {
    defer func() {
        b.doInsert()
        fmt.Println("Last insert")
        close(b.done)
    }()

    timer := time.NewTimer(b.duration)
    for {
        select {
        case <- timer.C:
            b.doInsert()
            fmt.Println("Timer Expired")
            timer.Reset(b.duration)
        case <- b.full:
            if !timer.Stop() {
                <-timer.C
            }
            b.doInsert()
            fmt.Println("Full")
            timer.Reset(b.duration)
        case <- b.mustExit:
            if !timer.Stop() {
                <-timer.C
            }
            return  
        }
    }
}

func (b *DataBuffer) Run() {
    go b.runAsync()
}
func (b *DataBuffer) Stop() {
    b.mustExit <- true
}

func (b *DataBuffer) WaitDone() {
    <- b.done
}

func main() {
    buf := NewDataBuffer(5, 1*time.Second)
    buf.Run()

    //simulate incoming data
    for k := 0; k < 30; k++ {
        buf.Append(k)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(10*k)*time.Millisecond)
    }
    buf.Stop()
    buf.WaitDone()  
}
```

**Note:**

- You need to implement proper error handling.
- The type of `incomingData` may be adjusted to your need

Comment: Just perfect. That is exactly what I needed and works like a charm after tweaking it to my use case. 1.000 thanks to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a goroutine that does the following:

- creates a new transaction and prepares statements
- continuously reads from an input channel (this receives the data from other parts of your program)
- times out after 10ms and commits the transaction, then creates a new one to accumulate more data

This function could look something like:

```
func transactionLoop(input chan Data) {
    tx := CreateNewTransaction() // This creates a new TX and prepares statements
    timeout := time.NewTimer(time.Millisecond * 10)
    for {
        select {
        case newData <- input:
            tx.Insert(newData)
        case <- timeout.C:
            // Too much time has passed: commit and create new tx.
            tx.Commit()
            // Create new transaction and launch timer.
            tx = CreateNewTransaction()
            timeout.Reset(time.Millisecond * 10)
        }
    }
}
```

This may do what you want, though there are quite a few details/problems left:

- there's absolutely no concept of passing errors back to the callers: **this is a terrible idea**
- shouldn't commit empty transactions
- if both channels are ready at the same time, the order is random (should be fine)
- you may want to commit in another goroutine, though you could then run into trouble if your commits take longer than 10ms.
- I haven't tested this, just jotting things down

Comment: Why don't use a `time.Timer`? It has stop and reset so `tx.Commit` takes too long won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about `time.Timer`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply here, I was without internet access. I need to have this mechanism as a general rule for all my backend since the goal is to call the DB as few times as possible: eventually inserts should group more than 1 connected client ! Say I have 100 clients connected to the same API endpoint, I need to group all 100 clients insert values and make only one DB insert.

Comment: Then instead of inserting individual data points, accumulate them and build a single insert at the end of the 10ms. Same overall logic, slightly different statements.

Comment: I may not see how to "catch" API calls and generally "rate limit" the inserts I guess. Let me throw an example: in a period of 1 second, say I receive 100.000 requests from 50.000 simultaneous users. I understand the code posted above will be instantiated 100.000 times, right ?

Comment: If you increase the timeout to 1s, it will do 100K requests, but the timeout is currently at the 10ms you mentioned above. The timeout is not between two incoming client requests, but the time from "initialize transaction" to "commit transaction".

Comment: I think I got what you mean. Then the channel will be the central gateway for all incoming requests, passing jobs down to `transactionLoop()`, right ? The code above is called only once for the whole app, correct ?

Comment: That's correct. There's only one call to `go transactionLoop(inputChan)` in your entire app, and the request handlers all have access to `inputChan` and write data into it. This is exactly what channels are good for as they do their own synchronization.

Comment: Cool, I'll test the code and see if i get the desired effect on insert perfs and post my findings here. Thanks for your assistance and patience :)